# GCS Connector Hadoop3 hadoop3-2.2.8 FileSystem.delete returns false but file/dir is actually deleted

Tags: java, hadoop, google-cloud-storage, hdfs, google-cloud-dataproc

In my Java application I have an implementation for a file-system, where my file class is a wrapper for Hadoop filesystem methods. I am upgrading the from [hadoop3-1.9.17](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/gcs-connector/hadoop3-1.9.17) to [hadoop3-2.2.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/gcs-connector/hadoop3-2.2.8) and I am using the [shaded jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/bigdataoss/gcs-connector/hadoop3-2.2.8/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.8-shaded.jar) of the new version.

My delete method implementation is as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean delete(boolean recursively) {
    return fs.delete(path, recursively);
}
```

Where fs is an instance of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` so this method calls `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.delete(Path, boolean)`

Frequently when calling the above delete method on a directory which contains files it returns `false` 'meaning dir/file NOT deleted' however when checking the directory is actually deleted at Google Cloud Storage.

Is there a change in the upgraded GCS connector causing this (caching of file-status i.e) or is there a configuration to fix this issue?

This is causing performance issues in my application since when a delete returns false retry / extra operations are done without being needed.

Comment: Hi @Selim Alawwa, can you provide the sample code which you have tried?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar the code is simply executing `fs.delete(path, recursively);` on some gcs path i.e "gcs://some-path" passing recursively as true. The result of this returns `false` even when the file is actually deleted at the bucket

Comment: Hi @Selim Alawwa, could you clarify where are you running your Java application and how you are using hadoop in your application?

Comment: It is a Java application, the same can be applied with a unit tests. Hadoop using hadoop jars 3.2.0

Comment: Hi @Selim Alawwa, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: @ShipraSarkar I have created this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259972867 from 2 weeks and nobody responded